Snopt Options for max_iter
I am using Drake's inverse kinematics solver. However, I tried to set the max_iter for the solver and got the following error:
  File "/home/jasmine/pivot/inverse_kinematics.py", line 230, in solve_with_initial_guess
    result = Solve(prog)
RuntimeError: Error setting Snopt integer parameter max_iter

This is how I am setting the max_iter value:
prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver().solver_id(), "max_iter", 100)

I also tried
solver_options = SolverOptions()
solver_options.SetOption(SnoptSolver().solver_id(), "max_iter", 100)      

and got the same error.
I verified that SnoptSolver is the solver being used by running the program without any options, and checking result.get_solver_id().
I saw a different post where it was suggested to use "Major Iterations Limit" and "Minor Iterations Limit". I tried those but didn't see any change in behavior in my IK results. I'm doubting that these settings are doing anything; I tried adding a setting to a string that would definitely not exist as an option and got no error message. So I think if options don't exist, they are silently being ignored.
solver_options.SetOption(result.get_solver_id(), "Major Iterations Limit", 1e20)
solver_options.SetOption(result.get_solver_id(), "Minor Iterations Limit", 1e20)
solver_options.SetOption(result.get_solver_id(), "this is not a valid solver option", 1e20)

Being able to adjust the number of iterations would be very helpful because it seems like the IK solver is getting very close to the desired solution but not close enough for the tolerance set. Here I print out the rotation given by the q_sol found by the solver. However result.is_sucess() returns false because it is not close enough to my rotation tolerance.
DEBUG:__main__:Solver failed to find a solution
DEBUG:__main__:Solver failed to reach goal rotation
DEBUG:__main__:Solver rotation: RotationMatrix([
  [0.8792933661331211, 0.44733902919402646, -0.1634960832375823],
  [0.44716027729885643, -0.8935592665926959, -0.039994043210623165],
  [-0.16398433669193657, -0.037942457037851686, -0.9857329797027369],
])
DEBUG:__main__:Goal rotation: RotationMatrix([
  [0.8734997743742637, 0.4560948494534895, -0.17022230309248323],
  [0.4573132513200487, -0.8886430852879852, -0.03432283695932748],
  [-0.16692134176071197, -0.04786392453455308, -0.984807753012208],
])
DEBUG:__main__:Diff: [[ 0.00579359 -0.00875582  0.00672622]
 [-0.01015297 -0.00491618 -0.00567121]
 [ 0.00293701  0.00992147 -0.00092523]]

Here is some more of my code for context:
self.ik = PydrakeInverseKinematics(self.plant, self.plant_context)
        self.ee_frame = self.plant.GetFrameByName(ik_frame)

        self.p_WG_lower = goal_pose.translation() - np.repeat(self.position_tolerance, 3)
        self.p_WG_higher = goal_pose.translation() + np.repeat(self.position_tolerance, 3)

        q0_node = initial_guess
        q0 = np.array(q0_node)

        self.ik.AddPositionConstraint(
            self.ee_frame,
            np.zeros(3),
            self.plant.world_frame(),
            self.p_WG_lower,
            self.p_WG_higher,
        )

        self.ik.AddOrientationConstraint(
            self.ee_frame,
            RotationMatrix(),
            self.plant.world_frame(),
            goal_pose.rotation(),
            0.0001,
        )

        self.ik.AddMinimumDistanceLowerBoundConstraint(0.001, 0.01)

        prog = self.ik.get_mutable_prog()
        q = self.ik.q()
        prog.AddQuadraticErrorCost(np.identity(len(q)), q0, q)
        prog.SetInitialGuess(q, q0)

        result = Solve(prog)

        prog.SetSolverOption(result.get_solver_id(), "max_iter", 100)
        result = Solve(prog)


Could you try solver_options.SetOption(result.get_solver_id(), "Major Iterations Limit", 2000)
solver_options.SetOption(result.get_solver_id(), "Minor Iterations Limit", 2000). 1e20 is a floating point, not an integer, so you could try the integer value

I just tried this and had the same exact behavior as without. Solver still fails with the same q_sol as before.

The SNOPT option name for iteration limit is indeed "Major iterations limit" (ditto "Minor ...").  (It is case-insensitive, so "Major Iterations Limit" also works.)
Here an example, given as a patch file against a Drake unit test:
--- a/bindings/pydrake/solvers/test/snopt_solver_test.py
+++ b/bindings/pydrake/solvers/test/snopt_solver_test.py
@@ -14,22 +14,25 @@ from pydrake.solvers import (
 
 class TestSnoptSolver(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_snopt_solver(self):
         prog = MathematicalProgram()
         x = prog.NewContinuousVariables(2, "x")
-        prog.AddLinearConstraint(x[0] + x[1] == 1)
+        prog.AddQuadraticConstraint(
+            Q=np.eye(2), b=np.zeros([2]), lb=0.0, ub=1.0, vars=x)
         prog.AddBoundingBoxConstraint(0, 1, x[1])
         prog.AddLinearCost(x[0])
+        prog.SetSolverOption(SnoptSolver.id(), "Major iterations limit", 0)
 
         solver = SnoptSolver()
         self.assertEqual(solver.solver_id(), SnoptSolver.id())
         if solver.available():
             self.assertTrue(solver.enabled())
             self.assertEqual(solver.solver_type(), SolverType.kSnopt)
 
             result = solver.Solve(prog, None, None)
-            self.assertTrue(result.is_success())
+            self.assertEqual(result.get_solution_result(),
+                             SolutionResult.kSolutionFound)
             numpy_compare.assert_float_allclose(
                 result.GetSolution(x), [0., 1.], atol=1E-7)
             self.assertEqual(result.get_solver_details().info, 1)
             np.testing.assert_allclose(
                 result.get_solver_details().xmul, np.array([0., -1])

The test prints this, indicating that the iteration limit was hit:
======================================================================
FAIL [0.003s]: test_snopt_solver (snopt_solver_test.TestSnoptSolver)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/nobackup/cache/bazel/_bazel_jwnimmer/10ee8aea36b37b216ef85df1451b64ad/sandbox/linux-sandbox/29681/execroot/drake/bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/bindings/pydrake/solvers/py/snopt_solver_test.runfiles/drake/bindings/pydrake/solvers/test/snopt_solver_test.py", line 32, in test_snopt_solver
    self.assertEqual(result.get_solution_result(),
AssertionError: <SolutionResult.kIterationLimit: -6> != <SolutionResult.kSolutionFound: 0>


I think if options don't exist, they are silently being ignored.

That is mostly not true.  If SNOPT is being used for the solve, and SNOPT options have been requested, all of the options will definitely be passed along to SNOPT, and if SNOPT does not accept any option, Drake will raise an exception.  However, SNOPT has a lot of option keywords and it's option parser (written in Fortran) is somewhat generous, so sometimes a user can make a typo in their option name and it ends up being accepted as a different option.

Ah ok. Printing out get_solution_result gives me SolutionResult.kSolverSpecificError. Unfortunately I tried looking at result.get_solver_details() but the Snopt Solver Details aren't very helpful for debugging this problem.

When SNOPT gives kSolverSpecificError that usually means the get_solver_details().info code is where to look next (using Sec 8.6 of https://web.stanford.edu/group/SOL/guides/sndoc7.pdf per the SnoptSolverDetails docs).
